# Append data to the child component

Tags: angular, typescript

Scenario: I have a dropdown in which I select the movie title, and hit the start button. For every one minute, my app calls the api and checks whether the booking is opened for the selected movie. When the booking is not opened, it should be logged in the terminal like html container. For every call the right side terminal should show

> 1. info about the api is calling (during the call)
> 2. info about movie status (after the call)
> 3. waiting (during the 1 minute gap)
> 4. starts again from 1 - 3

Here's the UI:

[image]

Here's my code:

spicinemas.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <form [formGroup]="movieForm" (ngSubmit)="getStatus()">
        <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="movie" name="movie" formControlName="movie">
          <option *ngFor="let movie of movies" [value]="movie">{{movie}}</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Start</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <app-terminal></app-terminal>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

spicinemas.component.ts

```
  getStatus() {
    interval(1 * 60 * 1000)
      .pipe(
        flatMap(() => this.service.checkStatus(this.movieForm.value.movie))
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
        const response: any = res;
        if (!response.status) { // false for booking not opened
        // implementation
        }
      });
  }
```

Currently the terminal is in separate component `<app-terminal>`. I need a suggestion on how to implement this?

Comment: look at this: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I know I can send the data from one component to another, but how to make that terminal display the data without erasing the previous data

Comment: use array as input

Comment: So the problem is, the log gets build up overtime, If I append all the logs in an array and pass it up to the terminal, the terminal should loop through all the array and display. basically I don't want that, I just want to send the current log which the terminal just append below the previous log.

Comment: you can create a method which dinamically inserts the new line. You can access it in the parent and simply call it.

Comment: This sounds good, but is this best practice to access one component's method from another component?

Comment: some says it is, others says it is not. An other way if you use input with onpush and implement OnChanges in which you dinamically add the new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use a service with a Subject, inject it into both components, publish your logs from `spicinemas.component.ts` and subscribe in `app-terminal`.

And if you don't want to databind an array in your `app-terminal`, you can manually append your elements there.